# Do aspects substitute repositories?

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design, aop, spring-roo

I started experimenting with Spring Roo just recently. It does a very nice job helping one build a domain model with integrated persistence rather quickly. As it adds persistence functionality in aspects, I started think about the following question:

Roo adds finders (load an instance of a class from the database which meets variable criteria) in an aspect to the actual class/entity. In DDD this is IMHO the responsibility of repositories. Repositories are explicit classes which show up in the design. Of course as an aspect the repository functionality is hidden in an entity and is pretty much invisible.

So here is the question: Is an aspect a real substitute for a explicit repository class? Are there any downsides to the Roo AOP approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding finders to your domain classes feels more natural from a user's point of view but it mingles your layers. Grails uses the same approach by adding static finder*() save(), ... methods.

Apart from the aestetics it might have practical drawbacks when not used in web application setting: 
Your domain classes are now tied to your database. If you transfer these objects to rich clients via RMI or HttpInvoker the client cannot and often may not use the find* methods because there is no session / database connection available on the client.

I generally prefer allowing domain classes to reference service layer interfaces to prevent an anemic domain model (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). This has its own set of drawbacks but at least provides a clear boundary. On the client the concrete implementation behind a service interface can then just proxy all method calls to the server (or just use a synamic proxy with spring remoting or sth similar).

So to answer your question: It might be a substitute but you should be aware of the possible negative consequences which make your domain classes (i.e. your core business logic) less portable between systems.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how complicated your applications persistence layer is and how much control you have over it. If your application is simple enough to be implemented via **JPA**, then it all could be handled via Roo aspects. However if you are mapping legacy tables or need advanced DB stuff, then you may find yourself in a situation where **Spring-JDBC** is the only way out and in these cases a repository/dao model may still be useful.

I consider it logical inconsistent (and a break of layer responsibility) to be mixing two persistence models and so as most of my applications requires such advanced DB constructs I stick strictly with a repository model.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding repository methods to domain objects is bad design. The right place would be static methods in the domain class. But domain objects and their management are two different things that should be separated. I would prefer domain objects and repositories.

I guess the motivation was to achieve something Rails/Grails like with Java.